# Send array from page to another

Tags: php

[table result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJgB0.png)     [vardumb result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHuqA.png)

is there anyway to display my data to fit correctly on cells ?

page1.php

`<td><input type='hidden' name='nom[]' value='".$row['nom']." ".$row['prenom']."'/></td>`

page2.php

`$idArrays = array($_POST['nom'], $_POST['montant'], $_POST['disponible_fiche'],$_POST['date_f'],$_POST['observation'] );`

```
   foreach ($idArrays as $idArray) {

        echo '<tr>';
            foreach ($idArray as $key ) {

               echo '<td>'.$key.'</td>';

           }
        echo '</tr>';

 }
```

Comment: You didn't mention what the problem is ..

Comment: how did you get the value? from database? if so share your MySQL code to fetch the result. Better make changes in result format so the for loop will automatically arrange the row columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make your `$idArray` a little bit different it works.
If all the arrays have the same length you can use `array_map` to create a new array in the right format.

```
$idArrays = array_map(null,$_POST['nom'], $_POST['montant'], $_POST['disponible_fiche'],$_POST['date_f'],$_POST['observation'] );
```

If some of the arrays are shorter, they will be padded with nulls to the length of the longest.

You can use your normal foreach then.

```
foreach ($idArrays as $idArray) {
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach ($idArray as $key ) {
        echo '<td>'.$key.'</td>';

    }
    echo '</tr>';
 }
```

## Explanation:

This method "zips" the arrays together, rather than making an array of the original arrays.

### Example:

```
<?php
$a = array("1","2");
$b = array("a","b");
$c = array("!","§");
print_r(array_map(null,$a,$b,$c));
print_r(array($a,$b,$c));
?>
```

### Outputs:

**with array_map:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => a
            [2] => !
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => b
            [2] => §
        )

)
```

**with normal array declaration:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => !
            [1] => §
        )

)
```

Comment: thank you so much you saved my day really appreciate it